# Сервер и андроид

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

Надо сделать программу для андроид в будущем может для айфон, на сервере должны храниться данные которые могут менять на андроиде пользователи и то что он изменил должно измениться у всех пользователей. с чего надо начать, хочу сделать сервер на google ingine на python и нужно ли будет использовать GCM

Answer (score 1):

Да можно. Смотрите [стартовую документацию по GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) - там расписан порядок взаимодействия вашего сервера с облаком GCM и мобильным приложением.

Требования к серверу [изложены здесь](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html) - неважно на чем он будет написан, важно что он должен поддерживать или HTTP или XMPP протоколы. В каждом из случаев четко прописаны специальные требования.

Чтобы не заниматься велосипедостроительством я бы посоветовал обратить внимание на готовую серверную инфраструктуру [Parse](http://www.parse.com) - он поддерживает все то о чем вы написали: хранение, синхронизацию, GCM и проч.

Answer (score 0):

Начать нужно с изучения Python (вы же хотите на Python), какого-нибудь веб фреймворка для него: например Django или Flask, а потом уже нужно непосредственно "делать"